# AngularJS - Bloquear Acción de Lista

Tags: angularjs, angular-directivas

Tengo una lista en angular que se recarga al seleccionar una fila obteniendo algunos valores de un servicio web de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servicio web se esta tardando alrededor de 4 segundos, lo cual me es un problema por que el usuario puede seleccionar de nuevo (antes de los 4 segundos) la fila de la lista, sin que esta se allá recargado y nuevamente se procesa la demás lógica de mi código que se ejecuta al seleccionar una fila.

La única solución que encontré es ocultando las filas cuando se selecciona hasta que se recarga nuevamente, pero por temas de estándar y definición no me es posible mantener esta solución. ¿Existe alguna manera de bloquear la acción que se ejecuta al seleccionar la fila?.

Intente con **disabled** y otras propiedades pero no funciona, hace algunos meses empece con angular, les agradezco cualquier aporte.

Comment: Hola, agrega parte de tu código para que lo podamos ver y evaluar. Adicionalmente, para bloquear algo así, intenta con el tag fieldset, por ej: <fieldset ng-disabled="isSaving"> ... inputs ...</fieldset>

Answer (score 0):

Si te he entendido bien, en tu componente crea una variable

```
esperando: boolean = false;
```

y cuando hagas esa llamada AJAX evita que el usuario pueda cambiar el dropdown añadiendole esta propiedad

```
[disabled]="esperando"
```

al momento de hacer la llamada AJAX setea la variable a true y cuando recibas respuesta la seteas a false entonces durante ese momento no podrá hacer más llamadas debido a que será de la clase disabled